# WebGL Globe (Google Experiments) doesn't display world map image

Tags: javascript, php, webgl, webgl-globe

My website display the globe can be found [here](http://warofworlds.net/1index.php).

Anyways, previously I was having issues with loading the globe itself. However I fixed that, the globe loads, but the world map image doesn't display on the globe as shown. The image can be found [here](http://warofworlds.net/world.jpg). A user with a similar issue [here](https://code.google.com/p/webgl-globe/issues/detail?id=6), had a solution that worked for him. However it didn't for me. Any suggestions?

Here's my globe.js (section):

```
shader = Shaders['earth'];
uniforms = THREE.UniformsUtils.clone(shader.uniforms);

uniforms['texture'].value = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('world.jpg');
```

and then:

```
opts.format = opts.format || 'magnitude'; // other option is 'legend'
console.log(opts.format);
if (opts.format === 'magnitude') {
  step = 3;
  colorFnWrapper = function(data, i) { return colorFn(data[i+2]); };
} else if (opts.format === 'legend') {
  step = 4;
  colorFnWrapper = function(data, i) { return colorFn(data[i+3]); };
} else {
  throw('error: format not supported: '+opts.format);
}
```

Edit; not* fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Your link to the globe gave me a 404. I had to remove the 1 before index.php http://warofworlds.net/1index.php to see your example. The map loaded correctly for me also. Are you loading your example in Chrome? I had similar problems when I tried loading webgl in Safari for Windows. Anyway, best of luck.